# Magento 2 Email templates

Tags: magento2, email-templates

This is an extract of Magento 2's email template **order_new.html**

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order confirmation" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message"
} @-->
```

and

```
{{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
```

My questions are:

1. What scripting language is this?
2. What do the double curly brackets stand for?
3. How can I access arrays? For instance `customerdata['name']` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This scripting language is called [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/). As Magento 2 is based on [Symfony](https://symfony.com/projects/magento), Twig is built-in already.
2. According to [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables), it used to display variables.
3. This one is already answered. [Pass Variable And Output In Custom Email Template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187855/pass-variable-and-output-in-custom-email-template)